# MongoReplicaSetClient，which uri should I connect to?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, database-replication

Let's say I have a replcaset of 3 machines(M1, M2, M3), and serveral other machines for hosting servers(S1, S2, ..Sn). I don't care much about real-time so `ReadPreference` will be set to `NEAREST`.

There's one thing that bothers me: As the doc says, the only required parameter of [`MongoReplicaSetClient`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/mongo_replica_set_client.html#pymongo.mongo_replica_set_client.MongoReplicaSetClient) is `hosts_or_uri`. But which mongodb uri should I use? Since I'll use the `NEAREST` option, does it make any difference if I:

1. Set `hosts_or_uri = M1` from S1 to Sn;
2. Spread the connection, 1/3 `hosts_or_uri = M1`, 1/3 `hosts_or_uri = M3`, 1/3 `hosts_or_uri = M3`;
3. Use `hosts_or_uri = M1, M2, M3`

I there is a difference, which is better? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify multiple members in the URI. Specifying one is sufficient to create the replica set connection to all set members; however, if you specify, e.g., only one machine in the uri, and that machine isn't up, the connection will fail. If you specify several and one machine is down (but the replica set is healthy) the connection will still succeed.